# Cookbook recommendation for finite element semiconductor simulation possibly using Sentaurus

Tags: resource-recommendations, semiconductor-physics, simulations

I've started work for my master's thesis using [Synopsys Sentaurus](http://www.google.com/search?as_epq=synopsys+sentaurus) for simulation of semiconductors. I'm interested in the device simulation, that is the physics, not the process simulations. The problem is that I'm stuck with the same problem for more than a month now, becasue hardly any of my simulations converge.

The main problem is, that I have very little experience in numeric analysis, and I don't have a good intuition on how to create good meshes, how to set error control parameters, etc.

Is there a book that basically gives tips and tricks on how to improve convergence behavior, and overall, how to set up a good simulation? I would be glad, if somebody could recommend me a book with a focus on drift-diffusion calculations (since that is the model I'm using), and the best would be if it would have Sentaurus in focus. However, I would be glad with a simple FEM book too, that explains enough, so that I can improve the quality of my simulations so that they at least converge. Thank you very much.

Comment: Slightly off-topic... Does your thesis advisor not have anything to say on the subject? FEM is a huge area... I would hope that he/she is at least able to guide you in the basics. Otherwise I would question the combination of advisor/topic.

Comment: To add a little bit to what Floris had to say: simulation software only contains the physics that the authors of the software put into it. You should be able to extract that from the documentation about the tool without having to run the software even once. These tools are only useful after you understand in detail what they do and even then they are only useful for the intended purpose, in this case to optimize device geometry and process parameters. I would suggest to ask a question that relates to the actual topic of your thesis, first, maybe that will help more?

Comment: Well, I guess Floris was right, and I'll write a mail to my advisor. It's just that I don't like running to him every day... But I guess that's what advisors are for. As for the documentation, it is definitely extensive, several thousand pages, but you don't really get ahead if you are just given a lot of formulas (at least I don't). I really need something that gives me some intuition.